# Cordova plugin error using custom framework in iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to add custom iOS framework to my cordova plugin. I copy the framework inside plugin directory and then add framework declaration to 
*plugin.xml* like this:

```
<framework src="src/ios/framework/iPhoneOS/SpeechSDK.framework" custom="true" arch="arm"/>
```

When I try to install plugin using either *plugman* or *cordova plugin add* I have an error:

> Error: Uh oh! Framework "%some_path%/tst_bing/platforms/ios/HelloCordova/Plugins/cordova-plugin-bing-speech/SpeechSDK.framework" for plugin cordova-plugin-bing-speech already exists in iOS platform

As I understand this is a bug in cordova, but I'm not sure - maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Hello. Looks like you are working on a BingSpeech plugin for Cordova isn't it ? That's something I'm interested in. Do you have plans to publish it and do need help ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't notice that arch attribute is Windows-only. But notice that it should be used with target-dir attribute.